# Add tabs and fields to custom joomla component

Tags: php, model-view-controller, joomla, components

How can i add more tabs and fields to a joomla component in backend,

-Tried editing the view xml file adding more fieldsets, no success
-Tried editing the edit file in view admin component, no success,

In other words i want to achieve this, just like the image
[image]

Any help?

Comment: What have you tried? What did you learn by looking at the components (all of the core components) that have tabs?  Just saying "tried editing" without showing code doesn't let anyone help you.

Comment: Well actualy i that using the core components as base, no success =) ty

Comment: You need to show the code, we don't have esp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set it to the view template `admin\views\*view_name\tmpl\*template_name.php`.

The structure that you have to use is:

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.startTabSet', 'myTab', array('active' => 'general')); ?>
    <?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.addTab', 'myTab', 'general', JText::_('COM_COMPONENT_NAME_TAB_1_NAME', true)); ?>

    ...

    <?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTab'); ?>
    <?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.addTab', 'myTab', 'advanced', JText::_('COM_COMPONENT_NAME_TAB_2_NAME', true)); ?>

    ...

    <?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTab'); ?>
<?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTabSet'); ?>
```

You could also check core components to get more examples.

As for the contents of each tab, you could restrict the loop to get the fields of one fieldset only using:

```
<?php foreach ($this->form->getFieldset("general") as $field): ?>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="control-label"><?php echo $field->label; ?></div>
        <div class="controls"><?php echo $field->input; ?></div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I Will try that today soon